# Ascending order of elements in doubly LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I've been trying to do this assignment but I've come up short and am absolutely clueless, so I'm wondering if anyone can give me a hand with implementing the methods, as well as maybe an explanation? I'm quite limited, which is why I'm dumbfound. Any help is greatly appreciated! There are two classes in total, in separate files, plus an iterator that's already implemented.

I have to implement a SortedLinkedList class which maintains the list elements in ascending order of key values in a doubly linked list.

```
/* LinkedListNode */
public class LinkedListNode {
public int key;               /* Key */
public LinkedListNode prev;   /* Pointer to the previous node */
public LinkedListNode next;   /* Pointer to the next node */
};

/*******************************************************
* Constructor: Initializes the linked list
*******************************************************/
SortedLinkedList();

/*******************************************************
* Removes all of the nodes from this list.
 *******************************************************/
void Clear();

/*******************************************************
* Returns the number of nodes in the list
*******************************************************/
int NoOfNodes(){return noOfNodes;}

/*******************************************************
* Inserts the given key in ascending order in the list
*******************************************************/
public void Add(int key);

/*******************************************************
* Removes the node that contains the key from the list 
* (if the key is found)
* Returns 0 upon successful deletion, -1 on error
*******************************************************/
public void Remove(int key);

/*******************************************************
* Removes a node from the list given a pointer to the node
*******************************************************/
public void Remove(LinkedListNode node);

/*******************************************************
* Searches a key in the list and returns a pointer
* to the list node that contains the key
*******************************************************/
public LinkedListNode Find(int key);
```

And the iterator:

```
public class LinkedListIterator{
private SortedLinkedList list;        /* Linked List */
private LinkedListNode pCurrentNode;  /* Pointer to the current node */
private int dir;                      /* 0: in ascending order, 1: in descending order */

/*******************************************************
* Constructor: Creates a LinkedListIterator
* dir: 0 means we want the items in ascending order
* dir: 1 means we want the items in descending order
*******************************************************/
public LinkedListIterator(SortedLinkedList _list, int _dir){
list = _list;
dir = _dir;

if (dir == 0) pCurrentNode = list.head;
else          pCurrentNode = list.tail;  
} //end-LinkedListIterator

/*******************************************************
* Returns a pointer to the next node in the list.
* Returns NULL if the end of the list has been reached
*******************************************************/
public LinkedListNode GetNextNode(){
  LinkedListNode ps = pCurrentNode;

  /* Move over to the next student */
  if (ps != null) {
    if (dir == 0) pCurrentNode = ps.next;
    else          pCurrentNode = ps.prev;
  } /* end-if */

  return ps;  
} //end-GetNextNode

/*******************************************************
* Returns TRUE if there are more nodes to return in the list
* Returns FALSE if the end of the list has been reached
*******************************************************/
public boolean HasMoreNodes(){
  return (pCurrentNode == null)?false:true;  
} //end-HasMoreNodes
};
```

Comment: methods should start with a lower case character

Comment: also don't use _ for field or variable names

Comment: i'm not supposed to edit those, they're already given and i'm just supposed to implement the methods

Comment: Why don't they teach the best pratices..... I'll never get it.

Answer (score 0):

1. write a method that sorts your list
2. implement all the methods in their basic functionality and call the sorting method before exiting the method

Also: I don't think the list nodes should not have the functionality.
the nodes just know their value and their neighbours

Comment: i'm still confused, i have no idea how to implement the add method, but i think once i understand that i'll be able to do the rest. how do i go about this?

Comment: well it's an assingment... you probably heard or even wrote down the needed information.